# Hibernate Cannot Instantiate Abstract class or interface: java.util.List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a parent-child relationship between entities MyUser and Circuit.
When I try to save MyUser using *myUserRepository.save(myUser)*, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : java.util.List
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.instantiate(ComponentType.java:580) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:500) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
```

Here are both the entities:

**MyUser:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class MyUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    private String chargeBeeCustomerID;

    private String company = null;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UsagePurpose usagePurpose = null;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CountryCode countryCode = null;

    private Instant createdAt = Instant.now();

    @Embedded
    private MyUserDetails details = new MyUserDetails();

    private double creditBalance = 0;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myUser", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Circuit> circuitList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
        this.circuitList.add(circuit);
        circuit.setMyUser(this);
    }

    public void removeCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
        this.circuitList.remove(circuit);
        circuit.setMyUser(null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

**Circuit:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Circuit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String circuitID;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ContinentCode continentCode;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CountryCode countryCode;

    @NotNull
    private boolean enabled;

    private boolean hasOnlyIPAclAccess;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> ipACL;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_my_user")
    private MyUser myUser;

    public Circuit() {
        circuitID = generateCircuitID();
        name = circuitID;
        enabled = true;
        hasOnlyIPAclAccess = true;
        ipACL = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static String generateCircuitID() {
        return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(15);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.circuitID.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        Circuit circuit = (Circuit) obj;
        return circuit.getCircuitID().equals(this.circuitID);
    }
}
```

Its notable then when I am first creating the user, the child(Circuit) is not yet created. It may be created a lot later. 
What is the reason behind this error and how to resolve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initiate a one to many relation with a default value. Instead of creating a new ArrayList, try initiating it using null instead.

This will solve your issue, since if you try to persist a User without any circuit assigned, it will work, otherwise, you will get that error.

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. But i learn that style from here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
The author uses an empty list to instaniate. Why doesn't it work in my case?

Comment: I can’t see your whole code, but here is what I think is happening. You are not adding any circuit to your user’s circuit list, before persisting it. So, since you have an empty list, it is causing that issue. Of course, if instead you have a null value, it simply won’t cause any issue.